# Unsupported operand types in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I click on a menu to edit I get this error

> Unsupported operand types

and the line that it shows is

```
{{ Form::select('submenu_id', array('default' => 'Please Select') + $submenu_options ) }}
```

and that is in my edit.blade.php

Comment: What you want to achieve? What is the content of `$submenu_options` ? If it's array it should work, so show us the content of this variable

Comment: `$submenu_options` is probably `null`, that's why you can't union it.

Comment: It works when I click on the create button

Comment: I managed to fix it. It was stupidness on my part. I hadn't added my code to make the select list work in the edit function in my controller

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.1 i solved it by doing

```
$categories = [''=>''] + Category::lists('name', 'id')->toArray();
return view('products.create', compact('categories'));
```

Or

```
$categories = [''=>''] + Category::lists('name', 'id')->all();
return view('products.create', compact('categories'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller you have not added submenu options, because of that reason it is showing this error :

```
return View::make('modulename.form')
    ->with('editMode', true)
    ->with('submenu_options','')
    ->with('customFields', $this->customField->getByTable('tablename'));
```